# Como checar se uma String é nula e adicionar em uma array?

Tags: java, android, array, nullpointerexception

Estou com um problema, possuo varias variáveis (String) com os seguintes nomes: textoTransferido1,  textoTransferido2 até 73 (textoTransferido73).

Em certos momentos a variável textoTransferido2 por exemplo pode assumir um valor vazio ou não, depende da situação.

Gostaria de montar um array, mas preciso verificar se a String textoTransferido1 até textoTransferido73 está vazia, senão adicionar na array.

Segue o meu código:

// RECUPERAÇÃO DE INFORMAÇÃO

```
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

    String textoTransferido1 = extra.getString("texto1");
    String textoTransferido2 = extra.getString("texto2");
    String textoTransferido3 = extra.getString("texto3");
    String textoTransferido4 = extra.getString("texto4");
    String textoTransferido5 = extra.getString("texto5");
    String textoTransferido6 = extra.getString("texto6");
    String textoTransferido7 = extra.getString("texto7");
    String textoTransferido8 = extra.getString("texto8");
```

// CRIANDO O ARRAY

```
        final String[] frases =
                {
                        textoTransferido1,
                        textoTransferido2,
                        textoTransferido3,
                        textoTransferido4,
                        textoTransferido5,
                        textoTransferido6,
                        textoTransferido7,
                        textoTransferido8
                }
```

No array não sei se o certo era criar um vetor que fosse conferindo cada item e caso não seja nulo então adicionaria o item na array.

Como o array não permite que o item seja nulo ou vazio, tenho que verificar a situação e só adicionar os que possuem valores.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um for + list.

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

List<String> textos = new ArrayList<>();
int numeroDeTextos = 8;

for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeTextos; i++) {
  String texto = extra.getString("texto" + i);

  // Verifica se é nulo ou vázio.
  if (texto == null || texto.trim().length() == 0) {
    continue;
  }

  textos.add(texto);
}

String[] arrayDeTextos = textos.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Você pode simplificar um pouco o código modificando o If para if(texto != null  && texto.trim().length() > 0) textos.add(texto);

Comment: Sim, eu sei, até pensei em colocar desta maneira, mas achei que ficaria mais legível da jeito que coloquei, coisa boba.

Comment: não seria mais legível ter a comparação `texto.Equals(String.Empty)`?

Comment: O que daria pra fazer é: `"".equals(texto)`, porém não funcionaria para textos que tenham apenas espaços, por isso que usei o `texto.trim ...`

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Leonardo!
Resolveu o meu problema, valeu por compartilhar o seu conhecimento.
Abraço!!!

Answer (score 2):

Se os seus Extras só forem ter os tais textos, faria dessa forma, para o código não ficar dependente do nome de cada extra ou da quantidade dos mesmos:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   List<String> textos = new ArrayList<>();
   for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
       String value = extras.getString(key);
       if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0)
          textos.add(value);
   }
}
```